# how to access embedded svg's elements via DOM

Tags: javascript, svg, dom

I want to change the path of a svg that I've placed into a page like this:

```html
    <div class="sx">
        <svg  width="250px" height="250px">
            <style>
                @import url(style.css);
            </style>

            <use id="anID"  href="test.svg#svg5" />
        </svg>
    </div>
```

the style is applied fine onto the `test.svg`, but the `use` is creating a shadow root which is not public.

I'm wondering if I can get the same styling results in another way (maybe via an `<object>` declaration) and at the same time getting access to the used svg nodes via the DOM.

Comment: Quite unclear, could you try to set up a minimal example with at least the content of the targeted element, and how it is (or how it is not) affected by the CSS rules?

Comment: @MichaelMullany that's not true, `d` is a presentation attribute you can set it through CSS and you can make it traverse the Shadow DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/2cf9o0tq/

Comment: whoa! when did that happen? use elements used to be impenetrable (I'm almost 100% sure). Deleted my comment so people don't see bad info.

Comment: Use elements never were "impenetrable" no, you always have been able to set e.g the fill style through CSS by targeting the use (if your cloned element didn't have a CSS rule with more importance). The fact that `d` is a presentation attribute is relatively new though, it came only in  SVG2.

Comment: Ah ok - I'm not crazy, just out of date :)